# Remove tuples within a list of tuples based on dictionary value within the tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a long list of tuples that contain a dictionary. I would like to remove tuples with a 'weight' value of 1.

```
List_example = [('WHT', 'WML, {'weight': 48}),
 ('WHHT','CCH', {'weight': 53}),
 ('WRT','KUF', {'weight': 1}),
 ('WHHT','RWH',{'weight': 1}))]
```

Desired output:

```
List_example = [('WHT', 'WML, {'weight': 48}),
 ('WHHT','CCH', {'weight': 53}))]
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: `List_example = [x for x in List_example if x[3]['weight'] != 1]`

Comment: @GiladGreen I tried: g = nx.DiGraph((x, y, {'weight': v>1}) for (x, y), v in Counter(edges).items()) and then edges2 = list(Counter(edges).items())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below

```
lst = [('WHT', 'WML', {'weight': 48}),
 ('WHHT','CCH', {'weight': 53}),
 ('WRT','KUF', {'weight': 1}),
 ('WHHT','RWH',{'weight': 1})]
 
new_lst = [x for x in lst if x[2]['weight'] != 1]
print(new_lst)
```

output

```
[('WHT', 'WML', {'weight': 48}), ('WHHT', 'CCH', {'weight': 53})]
```

Comment: "I would like to filter **out**..."